# How to call Oracle stored procedure with Char in out parameter?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Need a help. I am trying to call a pl/sql function from java. The pl/sql function has IN OUT CHAR parameter as one of the parameters. I am sending only 1 character in to it and assigning that char value to a temporary char value. But getting pl/sql numeric value error, further debugging shows the parameter's length is like 32767. Could not get how to resolve it. I am using Oracle 12c db and ojdbc7.jar to connect to it. Below is the java code and PL/SqL code.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Types;



public class TestInOutParam {

public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ragh:1521:inst1","schema1","schema1");




        OracleCallableStatement procCall = (OracleCallableStatement)con.prepareCall("{? = call TEMPPROC (?,?,?,?)}");

        String a = "ragh";
        String b="n";
        Integer c = 50;


        procCall.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
        procCall.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        procCall.registerOutParameter(3, Types.CHAR, 0, 1);
        procCall.registerOutParameter(4, Types.INTEGER);
        procCall.registerOutParameter(5, Types.DATE);

        procCall.setString(2, a);
        procCall.setString(3, b);
        procCall.setInt(4, c);
        procCall.setDate(5, getCurrentDate());



        procCall.executeUpdate();

    }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}
    }

private static java.sql.Date getCurrentDate() {
    java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
    return new java.sql.Date(today.getTime());
}
```

}

Below is the PL/SQL Code,

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP
(
 MSG  VARCHAR2(3000 BYTE),
 DT   DATE
 )
 /

 CREATE OR REPLACE function tempproc(a in out varchar, b in out char, c in            out integer, d in out date) return integer
 is
    errm varchar2(3000);
    tempb char(32);
    tempa varchar2(10);
    tempc integer;
    tempd date;
    result integer;
    begin

tempa := a;
insert into temp values('varchar value'||tempa, sysdate); commit;
tempc := c;
insert into temp values('integer value'||tempc, sysdate); commit;
tempd := d;
insert into temp values('date value', tempd); commit;
tempb := b;
insert into temp values('char value'||tempb, sysdate); commit;
commit;
return result;
 exception 
when others then
errm := sqlerrm;
 insert into temp values ('ex'||errm, sysdate);
 commit;
return 2;
end;
 /
```

Comment: Why you have set length for    `procCall.registerOutParameter(3, Types.CHAR, 0, 1);` but have not did it for `procCall.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);` ?

Comment: We are specifying the length of char datatype

Comment: Looks like a bug in ojdbc7; it seems to work OK with ojdbc6. The `maxLength` seems to set to 4000 if you give a value less than that, and since it's `char` it's space-padded to that length. Your `tempb` is then too small. Unless it's a known problem with a patch (and/or you want to raise a CR) you'll need to work around it in your PL/SQL code?

Comment: Thanks for the response Alex. Same code works, if i remove the IN OUT specification, I am finding same issue with ojdbc6, did you try using oracle 12c?

Comment: Tried with ojdbc6.jar it works good, without any change to the code.

Comment: It's working OK for me with the 11.2.0.3 32-bit instant client ojdbc6; but yes, I see the same problem with either ojdbc6 or ojdbc7 from the 12.1.0.1 instant client distribution. (Both hitting an 11gR2 DB; not sure that's relevant as it seems to be the driver causing it).

Comment: Thank you Alex for your response. It helps.